# Hide pagination bullets at Full Screen Vertical Scroll (FSVS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I am creating a web page locally and I have the style from FSVS https://github.com/lukesnowden/FSVS
But because the Top page will be the one that will have my menu and slider, I don't want it to have the pagination bullets. Any suggestion?
I tried using code like

```
 html.fsvs.demo #fsvs-body>.slide.nth-class-1 li{display: none;}
```

but it won't hide it. Here is the demo page of the FSVS also: http://luke.sno.wden.co.uk/full-screen-vertical-scroll

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html.fsvs .slide.nth-class-1 #fsvs-pagination li:first-child{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: This hides the first bullet from all pages. I want to hide all the bullets from the first page only

Comment: You can add references  class for your home page. you have any class in home body?

Comment: the first page has a class="slide nth-class-1 active-slide" and an id="fsvs-initial-setup" , just like the demo page that I provided. I just started creating the page, so most of the code is identical

Comment: When you click on next button then which class come on body tag? Can you provide your site link so that i better understand?

Comment: You mean the body class of the second page, right? active-slide-2 active-nth-slide-2  , exactly like here: http://luke.sno.wden.co.uk/full-screen-vertical-scroll#basic-html-setup

Comment: In this there is different class in first slide. try this
html.fsvs .active-slide-1 #fsvs-pagination li:first-child { display:none}

Comment: this hides the first bullet again. I changed your answer and I did it, it was this one: html.fsvs .active-slide-1 li { display:none;} thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
 html.fsvs .active-slide-1 li { display:none;}
```

did it!